# Prevent overlapping figures with alpha channel from shading each other?

Tags: svg, mix-blend-mode

Consider an SVG with two partly overlapping circles, both with `fill="currentColor"`. I do not control the value of the current color, it could be set to anything by code I have no control over.

I want the whole figure to have the same solid color. That works great if the images happends to have e.g. `color: red`. However, when the current color has an alpha channel the part where the circles overlap becomes darker.

I want to avoid that. Basically, I would like make the first image look like the second in this example:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="color: rgba(0,0,0,50%); width: 100px;">
    <circle cx="3" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
    <circle cx="7" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="color: rgb(50%,50%,50%); width: 100px;">
    <circle cx="3" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
    <circle cx="7" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
</svg>
```

Is this possible to accomplish, perhaps using a blend mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way, to achieve what you want, is just to turn the circles into a clipping path.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="color: rgba(0,0,0,50%); width: 100px;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="3" cy="5" r="3"></circle>
      <circle cx="7" cy="5" r="3"></circle>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="currentColor" clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to simply move the color to full opacity, this can be achieved with a relatively simple filter:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="color: rgba(0,0,0,50%); width: 100px;">
    <filter id="filter">
        <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic">
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="100"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
    <circle cx="3" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor" style="filter:url(#filter)"></circle>
    <circle cx="7" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor" style="filter:url(#filter)"></circle>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="color: rgb(50%,50%,50%); width: 100px;">
    <circle cx="3" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
    <circle cx="7" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
</svg>
```

If, as you described, you want to emulate the effect of the transparency on a colored background, it is a bit more complicated, and the result is not really perfect.

The following adds a white background separately behind the outline of each colored object.

Note two properties, though:

- `color-interpolation-filters:sRGB` is needed for correct color addition
- without `shape-rendering:crispEdges` you would get some artefacts where the objects overlap. But setting this comes at a price: you loose anti-aliasing everywhere. Depending on the shapes used, that could be quite visible.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="color: rgba(0,0,0,50%); width: 100px; shape-rendering:crispEdges">
    <filter id="filter" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB">
        <feFlood flood-color="#fff" flood-opacity="1" result="bg" />
        <feComponentTransfer in="SourceGraphic" result="opaque">
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="100"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
        <feComposite in="bg" in2="opaque" operator="in" result="combine" />
        <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="combine" operator="atop" />
    </filter>
    <circle cx="3" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor" style="filter:url(#filter)"></circle>
    <circle cx="7" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor" style="filter:url(#filter)"></circle>
</svg>
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" style="color: rgb(50%,50%,50%); width: 100px;">
    <circle cx="3" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
    <circle cx="7" cy="5" r="3" fill="currentColor"></circle>
</svg>
```