# How to create an SVG icon consisting of two overlapping shapes, one with a hole?

Tags: svg, icons

I have made a progress bar icon from two partially overlapping SVG shapes.
I would like the icon to have the same color as the surrounding text, so I set `stroke` and `fill` to [currentColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#currentcolor_keyword).

The icon is displayed correctly if the color of the surrounding text doesn't have alpha channel e.g. `color: black`. However, if the color of the surrounding text has alpha channel e.g. `color: rgba (0, 0, 0, 0.7)`, then the icon is darker where the shapes overlap.

How can I get the same color at each point of the icon?

```css
body { background-color: #eee; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 44 18" width="220" height="90">
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="40" height="11" rx="3" ry="3"
        stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
  <rect x="2" y="2.5" width="24" height="10" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

Question [Prevent overlapping figures with alpha channel from shading each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52881604/prevent-overlapping-figures-with-alpha-channel-from-shading-each-other) is very similar, but the accepted answer doesn't work in this case:

```css
body { background-color: #eee; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 44 18" width="220" height="90">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <rect x="2" y="2" width="40" height="11" rx="3" ry="3"
            stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
      <rect x="2" y="2.5" width="24" height="10" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="currentColor" clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
</svg>
```

**Update:**
I decided to draw the icon without overlapping parts, because it is much easier and it also looks good:

```css
body { background-color: #eee; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 44 18" width="220" height="90">
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="40" height="11" rx="3" ry="3"
        stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
  <rect x="4" y="4" width="23" height="7" rx="2" ry="2" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to user a mask. But if you don't change the geometry, you will get the same issue as with @InvisibleGorilla's solution: you will get antialiasing artifacts.

```css
body { background-color: #eee; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 44 18" width="220" height="90">
  <defs>
    <mask id="cutout">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <use xlink:href="#bar" fill="black" />
    </mask>

    <rect id="bar" x="2" y="2.5" width="24" height="10" />
  </defs>
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="40" height="11" rx="3" ry="3"
        stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent"
        mask="url(#cutout)" />
  <use xlink:href="#bar" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

To fix the antialiasing artifacts, move your bar so that it is positioned at a whole pixel (`y="2"`) instead of a half pixel (`y="2.5"`).  You still might still see very slight artifacts at some scales. But it should be a lot better.

```css
body { background-color: #eee; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 44 18" width="220" height="90">
  <defs>
    <mask id="cutout">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
      <use xlink:href="#bar" fill="black" />
    </mask>

    <rect id="bar" x="2" y="2" width="24" height="10" />
  </defs>
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="40" height="11" rx="3" ry="3"
        stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent"
        mask="url(#cutout)" />
  <use xlink:href="#bar" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the rect where `fill` has `currentColor`, add a rect with the exact same attributes but with a white fill directly before it (so that it gets drawn underneath it in the svg).

See snipped below:

```html
<style>
  body { background-color: #eee; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
</style>

<svg viewBox="0 0 44 18" width="220" height="90">
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="40" height="11" rx="3" ry="3"
        stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
  <rect x="2" y="2.5" width="24" height="10" fill="white" />
  <rect x="2" y="2.5" width="24" height="10" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

You could also change the order of your rects and add a matching white rect under the one where the `stroke` has `currentColor`.

Here's the updated snippet using background color and underlying both rects. I've tested on Chrome and Firefox on Mac and I don't see any lines from the background color rects.

```html
<style>
  body { background-color: #232b32; color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.7); }
</style>

<svg viewBox="0 0 44 18" width="220" height="90">
<rect x="2" y="2" width="40" height="11" rx="3" ry="3"
        stroke="#232b32" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
  <rect x="2" y="2" width="40" height="11" rx="3" ry="3"
        stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" fill="transparent" />
  <rect x="2" y="2.5" width="24" height="10" fill="#232b32" />
  <rect x="2" y="2.5" width="24" height="10" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>

<p>Some text</p>
```

Here's a screenshot of when I run this snippet.
[image: Here's a screenshot of when I run this snippet.]

Comment: Unfortunately, I see a white line around the last `rect` (tested in Google Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10).  Additionally, it doesn't work for `body { background-color: #232b32; color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.7); }`.

Comment: I've updated my answer and added an additional snippet. Now both rects have underlying copies with the background color. I'm on a Mac so I can't see the other issue with the white line. Do you see it when you run the snippet here or just in your project? Maybe you can take a screenshot and update the question with the screenshot so that issue can be seen.

Comment: The line was an antialiasing artifact. I changed `x="2" y="2.5"` to `x="3" y="3"` as Paul LeBeau advised, and it doesn't show anymore. But the current background color #232b32 shouldn't be used in icon definition, because it can change like a font color - that's why I used `currentColor`.